# How to pass SOAP Request Properties in PHP (as shown in SoapUI)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

In SOAP UI I am able to pass a few request properties, specifically `Username`, `Password` and `WSS-Password Type`.  They are marked in the screenshot below by a red box:

[image: Marked up screenshot of SOAP UI]

I've tried passing these values in PHP as the second parameter of the SoapClient function like so:

```
$soap = new SoapClient('https://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl',
        array("Username" => "blah@example.com",
              "Password" => "notarealpassword",
              "WSS-Password Type" => "PasswordText"));
```

But I get the security error: `An error occurred when verifying security for the message.`

The WSDL I'm calling itself is here, **though my question is about passing the request properties this way in general**, really: https://rev-int.api.us.fleetmatics.com/Vehicle/SageQuest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl

Comment: Have you got any clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that a security header with username and password is sent along with the message itself, but you can not see this header in the normal window in SoapUI.

Click "http log" in the bottom panel of SoapUI to see the whole communication. Look thoroughly for Header ithems.

If any header ithems, they must be set before your function SOAP call in PHP, but after you've constructed the client.

Use `__ setSoapHeaders()` to set headers in PHP

Comment: Negative.  None of the strings passed are apparent anywhere in the headers.  A session ID is, which I'm suspecting is from WSS which might be as described here http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#97273 but I'm still not even sure how to implement that solution, since all my attempts have failed.

Comment: If there is an sessionID but no username/password, then I would expect it is not the initial communication with the server you are looking at. My believe is, that there has been a prior one, where the username and password are sent to the server.

I'm familiar with the page you are linking to, and the information there is ok, though it can be done much more simple in my opinion, when you know the xml code: `$xml=copy of Security header from SoapUI; $securityToken = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML); $header=new SoapHeader($nsWSSE, 'Security', $securityToken); $client->__setSoapHeaders($header)`

Comment: Where are you getting the `copy of Security header from SoapUI` from?  my headers section is completely blank (as you can see in the image I attached as `Headers (0)`, just above the 1749ms response time).

Comment: Click "http log" in the bottom panel of SoapUI to see the whole communication. Look thoroughly for Header ithems.

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting that security error.

I used the soapui tool as well. But i had better success with the Chrome App called Boomerang.

You need to choose WSS PasswordText under Auth and then everything just seems to work.

Then you can even copy the xml that Boomerang generates into PHP and it works as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is not what the OP wanted. I know this is an old question but OP needed to pass extra properties to its soap request. He already got the request. This is about a configuration topic.